# Reducing the complexity of an o(n^3) c++ code

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, for-loop, code-complexity

I would like to reduce the complexity of the following algorithm. Basically, it takes a word as an input and calculates the number of unique letters within it (the "entropy" of the word). My current solution employs 3 embedded for loops, which comes out to a complexity of o(n^3). Since this code is part of a bigger project (we built a solver for the game known as boggle), I was hoping to reduce the complexity of my algorithm in order to reduce its execution time. Thanks in advance!

```
int wordEntropy(string word)
{

int length = word.length();
int uniquewords = length;
string compare = word;
char save[17];
int cond=0;

for (int ii=0; ii < length; ii++)
{

    for (int jj=ii+1; jj < length; jj++)
    {
        for (int kk=0; kk<= ii; kk++)
        {
            if (save[kk] == word[ii]) {cond++;}
        }
        if (word[ii] == word[jj])
        {
            if (cond>0) {break;}
            uniquewords--;
        }
    }

    save[ii] = word[ii];
    cond = 0;

}
return uniquewords;
}
```

Comment: Keep it simple? Loop over the word, recording which letters you've seen in a bitset. At the end, sum the bitset. Time complexity O(n+m) where n is the length of the word, and m the size of the alphabet (ie. 26).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is really about performance, depending on the range of valid characters something like this may be faster:

```
std::size_t wordEntropy( const std::string & word )
{
    unsigned char seen[256] = { 0 };
    for( unsigned char c : word )
    {
        ++seen[ c ];
    }
    return std::count_if( & seen[0], & seen[ 0 ] + 256,
                          []( unsigned char c ) { return c != 0; } );
}
```

But obviously, this is a little bit harder to maintain. This solution has **guaranteed** complexity of O(n) and it does not make any dynamic memory allocations.

Alternative version that does not have problems if a character occurs more than 255 times:

```
std::size_t wordEntropy( const std::string & word )
{
    bool seen[256] = { false };
    for( unsigned char c : word )
    {
        seen[ c ] = true;
    }
    return std::count_if( & seen[0], & seen[ 0 ] + 256,
                          []( bool t ) { return t; } );
}
```

Comment: You probably need to write that as `for (unsigned char c : word)`, since many C++ implementations treat the range of `char` as `[-128, 127]`.

Comment: You also need to replace that `256` with a `std::numeric::limits<std::string::value_type>::max()` in case you hit a 16 bit char.

Comment: Yes, all of the things above are true. In addition, if a character occurs more often then 255 times in a word, the original algorithm fails, I provide an alternative version that fixes this issue.

Comment: One other thing I would mention is that your Complexity with this solution is `O(N)` with respect to the number of chars representable on the target machine, not `O(N)` with respect to the size of the input word.

Comment: @Xirema Actually, both is true. `O(M+N)` where `M` is the number of representable characters / characters that may be in the word by contract and `N` is the number of characters in the word, i.e. the size of the word.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, introduced it into my code and it runs smoothly. I'll get back to you once my partners implement it in the boggle solver.

Comment: @PatrickFuentes Personally, I'd go for std::sort + std::unique, but if it is about performance, make sure to compare it to the other solutions. For short word length I'd expect the std::sort + std::unique appraoch to outperform this one.

Answer (score 13):

One cheap solution is just to stick the characters in an `unordered_set`, which is a hashset (amortized O(1) insertion and lookup):

```
#include <unordered_set>

int wordEntropy(const std::string &word) {
    std::unordered_set<char> uniquechars(word.begin(), word.end());
    return uniquechars.size();
}
```

This yields a complexity of O(n), which is as good as it gets.

Comment: On average this is O(N) but it could hit a worst case of O(N^2).  Not sure exactly what you would need to have to make this worst case though.

Comment: @NathanOliver You'd need a badly implemented `unordered_set` to hit the worst case, or a bad implementation of `hash<char>`. That's what causes performance degradation in Hash Sets.

Comment: @Xirema So it is related to collisions then?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep.

Answer (score 10):

Do the computation in place, without any extra (and time-consuming) memory allocations:

```
std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
auto last = std::unique(word.begin(), word.end());
return last - word.begin();
```

Comment: Worth noting that for long strings this will be O(n log n). (For typical Boggle words, the difference probably won't matter).

Comment: @nneonneo - for typical Boggle words, the difference (compared to using some form of set) is important: all the memory overhead and runtime complexity of a set far outweighs the "extra" work needed to sort a short word. There's far more to performance evaluation than asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are short, then you should be more worried about the memory allocs than big-O.  Either way, here's a faster solution.

Since you mentioned that this is for a boggle game, and the input to this function is a string named "word", I am assuming that you have already verified that all the characters in "word" are ascii alphabet characters.  If so, here's probably the fastest case-invariant entropy count:

```
int word_entropy ( std::string const& word )
{
    uint32_t bit_map = 0;
    for ( char const ch : word )
        bit_map |= static_cast <uint32_t> ( 1 ) << ( ch & 31 );
    return __builtin_popcount ( bit_map );
}
```